# read yelp api response

Tags: python, api, yelp

Iam new to python & API searches. I am having issues reading yelp API responses in python. any help would be great. thanks.

```
> params = {
>     'term': 'lunch,pancakes' } 

> response=client.search('Los Angeles',**params)
```

Here is the output:

```
<yelp.obj.search_response.SearchResponse object at 0x138ad7a58>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SearchResponse` contains the `businesses` list that will match your term [1].

Try this:

```
for business in response['businesses']:
     print(business['name'])
```

[1] https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api

Comment: thanks for the response. But i've tried running the script above and im getting an error. ive also tried using different fields, but no luck. seems like the response object can't be broken down anymore (i dont know)? please see below.



TypeError: 'SearchResponse' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1):

You may need to do a JSON conversion to make it subscriptable .

```
import json
json_response = json.loads(response)
for business in json_response['businesses']:
     print(business['name'])
```